# Should I distribute Root CA or Intermediate CA certificates to client?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure

I've been following this tutorial to create a Root CA, intermediate CA, and server certificate.

I can verify:

- the intermediate certificate with the root certificate
- the server certificate with the intermediate certificate

But I can't verify the bundle intermediate cert + server cert with the root certificate.

In other words:

```
# verify intermediate cert with root cert: OK
openssl verify -CAfile root/certs/ca.cert.pem intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem

# verify server cert with intermediate cert: OK
openssl verify -CAfile intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem intermediate/certs/my.domain.cert.pem

# create bundle intermediate cert + server cert
cat intermediate/certs/my.domain.cert.pem intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem  > certs/my.domain.bundle.pem

# checking bundle with the root cert: NOT OK
openssl verify -CAfile root/certs/ca.cert.pem intermediate/certs/my.domain.bundle.pem # NOT OK
```

That confuses me because I thought I would deploy the Root CA certificate on clients, and have the server use the bundle intermediate cert + server cert.

**Does that mean I should only deploy the intermediate cert on clients, and have the server use only the server cert?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a server must hand over the server certificate and the intermediate certificates.  To quote RFC 5246 (emphasis mine):

> If the server is authenticated, its certificate message must provide a
>   **valid certificate chain** leading to an acceptable certificate
>   authority.

It is preferred that the server do this, as opposed to distributing intermediates to all the clients, because trying to make sure all your clients get and keep the proper intermediates is a lot harder than handing them out each time as part of the handshake.

Echoing this setup, you should try, instead of using the bundle as your target, using the `-untrusted` argument to `openssl verify` to integrate the intermediates:

> -untrusted file
>
> A file of additional untrusted certificates (intermediate issuer CAs)
>   used to construct a certificate chain from the subject certificate to
>   a trust-anchor. The file should contain one or more certificates in
>   PEM format. This option can be specified more than once to include
>   untrusted certificates from multiple files.

Comment: What should happen with each intermediate certificate's private key?  I'm assuming that they are NOT installed on the server like the server certificate's private key - correct?

Comment: Correct, the Intermediate's Private Key is closely held by the CA, and used to sign the Server certificate; thereafter, the Intermediate's Public Key is distributed to help verify the Server certificate.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the quick response.